"Long" underbrace in tikz-cd
How does one achieve an underbrace spanning multiple "columns" in tikz-cd?
E.g., say, in following diagram, one wants an underbrace spanning from B up until D,
  \documentclass{article}
  \usepackage{tikz-cd}
  \begin{document}

  \begin{tikzcd}
        A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r] & C \arrow[r] & D
  \end{tikzcd}

  \end{document}

?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

I beg your pardon; I adjusted the code. Thank you for the remark.

Thanks! Much better question now!

You could use brace decoration from decorations.pathreplacing library.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
    execute at end picture={
    \draw[decorate, decoration={brace,mirror}]
    (mycd-1-2.south west) -- 
    (mycd-1-4.south east);
    }]
    A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r] & C \arrow[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}


Or, more elegant, calligraphic brace:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, calligraphy}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tikzcd}[
    every matrix/.append style={name=mycd},
    execute at end picture={
    \draw[decorate, decoration={calligraphic brace, amplitude=8pt, 
    mirror}]
    (mycd-1-2.south west) -- 
    (mycd-1-4.south east);
    }]
    A \arrow[r] & B \arrow[r] & C \arrow[r] & D
\end{tikzcd}
\]
\end{document}



Thank you very much indeed.

@Sinistrum You're welcome! Thank you for accepting my answer!
